# How to invoke concurrent.futures with a function that uses two arguments (one List argument and one that is not a list)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've built a function where I want to leverage some multi-threading in Python. This function takes two arguments: A List type of argument (where I leverage multi-threading) and a non iterable variable. The way that I've coded is not working and I don't know how to invoke it

("ssns" variable would be a List of ssn and cursor is simply the cursor used for writing in SQL Server DB). Thank you!

```
def main(ssns):

    t1 = time.perf_counter()
    create_folders()

    conn = pymssql.connect(db.server, db.user, db.password, db.db)
    cursor = conn.cursor(as_dict=True)

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        results = executor.map(f.get_pdf_multi_thread, ssns, cursor)

    conn.commit()
    cursor.close()
    conn.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm understanding the question correctly:

You have the function `f.get_pdf_multi_thread` which takes 2 arguments: a `List` of SSNs and a `cursor`. You want to call `f.get_pdf_multi_thread(ssns, cursor)`, using the `ThreadPoolExecutor` class for asynchronicity.

**Answer:**
I think you want to either:

(1) use `executor.submit` instead of `executor.map` in order to accept multiple arguments, or

(2) change your function to accept two non-iterables, e.g. `f.get_pdf_single(ssn, cursor)`, and use an anonymous (lambda) function within the call to `executor.map`:

```
results = executor.map(lambda s, c: f.get_pdf_single(s, c), ssns)
```

The method `executor.map` actually does the work of making multiple calls to the given function AND distributing them across threads for you. The function passed in should be a function that takes **one item** of your iterable as an argument.

Comment: Thank you! executor.submit did the job for me. However, in the second approach, where do you insert the "cursor" input parameter?